Let $f:K\to L$ be a surjective $\wedge$-preserving map between lattices. If $f(x)\leq y'$, is there some $y\in K$ such that $f(y)=y'$ and $x\leq y$?
Let $f:K\to L$ be a surjective $\wedge$-preserving map between lattices. So $K$ and $L$ are assumed to be lattices and $f$ is not assumed to preserve joins. Then, if $f(x)\leq y'$, is there some $y\in K$ such that $f(y)=y'$ and $x\leq y$ ?
When, $f$ is a lattice homomorphism, this claim holds in virtue of the preservation of joins and is easy to show:
Suppose $f(x)\leq y'$. By surjectivity, there is some $y''\in K$ such that $f(y'')=y'$. Now, surely $x\leq x\vee y''$. But $f(x\vee y'')= f(x)\vee f(y'')=f(x)\vee y'=y'$. So by generalizing on $x\vee y''$, we have found some $y$ such that $f(y)=y'$ and $x\leq y$.
My Question is whether the claim holds when $f$ no longer preserves joins.
A counter example, a strategy, or a proof is welcome!

A counter-example:
Let $K$ be the four element lattice on $\{0,x,y,1\}$, with $x$ and $y$ incomparable, and $L$ the 3-element chain with $f(x) < y' < 1$, and $f(0)=f(x)$, $f(y)=y'$ and $f(1)=1$.
Since $y$ is the only element that maps to $y'$ and $y$ in incomparable with $x$, your claim doesn't hold.
(Notice $f$ doesn't preserve joins since $f(x \vee y) = 1 > y' = f(x) \vee f(y)$.)

Thanks a lot! Simpler than I expected.
